# HTML input label to python file

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, input

How do I take the input from an Html input label and use it in a python file without having to create a local host? I don't need to save the input but just run it in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_text = request.POST.get('the_post')
        response_data = {}

        post = Post(text=post_text, author=request.user)
        post.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['postpk'] = post.pk
        response_data['text'] = post.text
        response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
        response_data['author'] = post.author.username

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Comment: <form method="POST" id="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper" id="the_post">
        {{ form.text }}
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div> <!-- errors go here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="tiny button">
</form>

Comment: Your solution doesn't work